# How is l[i] += v v=v-1 evaluated?

Tags: python

How does `v=v-1` come in to play in the following line?  is the value that is added to the `l[i]` indecency `v=v-1`?

```
l=[20,40,30]
v=[6]
 def thing_two(l,v):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] += v v=v-1
```

What value do `l` and `v` end with?

Comment: That code is syntactically invalid.  Where did you get it?  Assignments are statements in Python, so you cannot do them inline.

Comment: It isn't. It is a syntax error.

Comment: Seems like you're missing a line break

Comment: The code appears to be from [this](https://www3.amherst.edu/~sfkaplan/courses/2014/fall/COSC-111/documents/sample-mid-term-solutions.pdf) sample mid term.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's a perfectly valid question. Just because the code is wrong, doesn't mean it was a error from the poster's part.

Comment: Kroltan: it's a question about a short code that was not even tried.

Comment: @Kroltan Per the downvote mouseover: "this question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score -2):

The code should look like this:

```
l=[20,40,30]
v=[6]
def thing_two(l,v):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] += v 
        v=v-1
```

You are missing a line break.

```
>>> print v
[6]
>>> print l
[20, 40, 30]
```

The function does not modify `l` and `v`, because it's never called here.  You need more code.

This is the entire code from the midterm linked above:

```
def thing_one(x):
    y = 0
    if x == 1:
        y = x
        x = 2
    if x == 2:
        y = -x
        x = 3
    elif x == 3:
        y = 2 * x
        x = 2 * y
    else:
        y = x
    print('x = ' + str(x))
    print('y = ' + str(y))


def thing_two(l, v):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] += v
        v = v - 1


def main():
    thing_one(7)
    thing_one(3)
    thing_one(1)
    l = [20, 40, 30]
    v = 6
    thing_two(l, v)
    print('l = ' + str(l))
    print('v = ' + str(v))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Simply put that into a file and run it.  This question is embarrassingly bad.

Comment: Might be related to the nature of the question, which appears to be a (bad) copy/paste from a mid term example exam.